# Fully Distributed Hadoop Cluster - Automatic Failover HA Cluster with Zookeeper & QJM

Tags: hadoop2, high-availability

I have set up my Fully Distributed Hadoop Cluster - Automatic Failover HA Cluster with Zookeeper & QJM by folowing the below link.

http://hashprompt.blogspot.in/2015/01/fully-distributed-hadoop-cluster.html

```
hduser@ha-nn01:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin$ ./zkServer.sh start
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED

hduser@ha-nn01:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.7/bin$ jps
2919 Jps
2895 QuorumPeerMain
```

Everything is fine up to now. When I type the below command:

```
hduser@ha-nn01:/opt/hadoop-2.6.0$ bin/hdfs zkfc –formatZK
```

I got the **below error message** and I don't how to resolve this.

```
Error:
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=i386
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-24-generic
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/opt/hadoop-2.6.0
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=ha-nn01:2181,ha-nn02:2181,ha-nn03:2181 sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.ha.ActiveStandbyElector$WatcherWithClientRef@deea7f
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server ha-nn01/192.168.71.138:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
15/12/09 04:31:07 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to ha-nn01/192.168.71.138:2181, initiating session
15/12/09 04:31:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server ha-nn01/192.168.71.138:2181, sessionid = 0x1518612d0000000, negotiated timeout = 5000
Usage: java zkfc [ -formatZK [-force] [-nonInteractive] ]

15/12/09 04:31:08 INFO ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Session connected.
15/12/09 04:31:08 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1518612d0000000 closed
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Bad argument: –formatZK
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.badArg(ZKFailoverController.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doRun(ZKFailoverController.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$000(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.run(ZKFailoverController.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.main(DFSZKFailoverController.java:180)
15/12/09 04:31:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

**Set up:**

```
192.168.71.138  ha-nn01
192.168.71.139  ha-nn02
192.168.71.140  ha-nn03
192.168.71.141  ha-dn01
192.168.71.142  ha-dn02
192.168.71.143  ha-dn03    
192.168.71.144  ha-client
```

**Note:**

> HDFS-SITE.XML File Configuration:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>3</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///hdfs/name</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///hdfs/data</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>auto-ha</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.auto-ha</name>
  <value>nn01,nn02</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
  <value>ha-nn01:8020</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn01</name>
  <value>ha-nn01:50070</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
  <value>ha-nn02:8020</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.auto-ha.nn02</name>
  <value>ha-nn02:50070</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
  <value>qjournal://ha-nn01:8485;ha-nn02:8485;ha-nn03:8485/auto-ha</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
  <value>/hdfs/journalnode</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
  <value>sshfence</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
  <value>/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled.auto-ha</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>ha-nn01.hadoop.lab:2181,ha-nn02.hadoop.lab:2181,ha-nn03.hadoop.lab:2181</value>
 </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the command "hdfs zkfc -formatZK" from the microsoft word, sometimes the '-' is longer than the real, so in the terminal don't understand this line.